# Call XAgent and Standby Dialog Custom Control

Tags: xpages, standby

I have Fred Norling's amazing Standby Dialog custom control working on partial refreshes in my applications.

I have one use case though where I am unsure how to utilize it. I am calling an XAgent from a button to export a document collection to Excel (Paul Calhoun's example).

```
context.redirectToPage("ExcelExport");
```

Everything works as expected. The Excel file is generated but because it takes a little while I'd like to use the Standby Dialog custom control to indicate that the file is being processed.

As far as I am aware, it can can only be called during a partial refresh though. Any ideas on how to implement it in such a scenario?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I moved my code out of the XAgent and into the button itself. Changed the event to a partial update which triggered the Standby Dialog. Finally added Sven's XSnippet to cancel the partial refresh after the Excel file was generated, since the spinner did not seem to stop after the file was generated.

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=cancel-partial-refresh 

I thought that resolved it but apparently not. It terminates the partial refresh but the excel spreadsheet does not get saved so if anyone has any suggestions, please feel free to chime in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an small Iframe to load the xagent in. Because the standby widget only works with partial refresh

Set the iframe src from client side js. Add two new functions to my standby widget to manually show and hide the standby loader.

Add this to the show function

StandbyDialog_Do=true
   StandbyDialog_Started()

And this to the hide function
StandbyDialog_Completed()